# Setting the itemsource of a Listbox to a single column Datatable

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatable

i have a single column datatable and a listbox
in the following function i am trying to set the listbox item source to the datatable but it displays the rows as System.Datarow

```
Private Sub setghostshopslistitemsource()
        GhostShopsList.Items.Clear()
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & mydocumentddir & "\Settings\Settings.mdb")
        GhostsDatatableda = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Ghost From GhostsTable", con)
        GhostsDatatableda.Fill(GhostsDatatable)
        GhostShopsList.ItemsSource = GhostsDatatable.DefaultView
    End Sub
```

so what is wrong with the last line?
The Datatable Look like

Ghosts

Text1

Text2

Text3
.
.
.

and i just want to display each text in the listbox

using the above function the listbox displays

System.Data.DataRow

System.Data.DataRow

System.Data.DataRow

.

.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify how the rows should be displayed.  If you just need a text box, then write something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ghost}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

The items are still rows, try setting the [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) to `"[0]"` to bind to the first column values.